# Haskell: Functions in list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am teaching myself Haskell, and playing with list comprehensions. I wrote this list comprehension:

```
[ c | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..4], let c = hyp a b, c == round c]
```

I hoped it would produce the list of values c where c is an integer (c == round c), which would be only 5, but it does not compile. Playing around some more, I've found I can't really embed any functions in a list comprehension, I'm sure there is a way, I just don't know how.

Here's the error code:

```
<interactive>:158:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘it’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Floating t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Floating Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Floating Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
      In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what your `hyp` looks like, but you could try `c == fromIntegral (round c)` in the last statement of the comprehension

Comment: That was it, thanks so much! I'll just have to look into the role of fromIntegral before moving forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, include necessary definitions in a question like this.

```
hyp :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
hyp a b = sqrt $ a^2 + b^2
```

Now. *You can “embed” functions all right in list comprehensions*. Apparently you just chose some unfortunate ones! `round` has the following type:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :t round
round :: (Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
```

So, for `round c == c` to make sense, you'd need to have a number type that's both an instance of `Integral` and of `RealFrac`. In other words, this type would contain fractions, yet all its elements would be integers<sup>†</sup>. Well, you can't have your cake and eat it too!

This problem would have been much more evident, like so often in Haskell, if you had actually written out some type signatures. While fooling around like that, it often helps to just select some simple example type. Perhaps the most reasonable thing would seem:

```
Prelude> [ c | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..4], let c = hyp a b, c == round c] :: [Integer]
<interactive>:6:41:
    No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘hyp’
    In the expression: hyp a b
    In an equation for ‘c’: c = hyp a b
    In the expression:
        [c |
           a <- [1 .. 3], b <- [1 .. 4], let c = hyp a b, c == round c] ::
          [Integer]
```

Ok, so `Integer` doesn't work because you're trying to do real arithmetic, with those square roots in `hyp`. This is not possible with `Integer`, you need a `Floating` type like `Double`. Let's try that:

```
Prelude> [ c | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..4], let c = hyp a b, c == round c] :: [Double]

<interactive>:8:55:
    No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of ‘round’
    In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘round c’
    In the expression: c == round c
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: c == round c
```

Ok, this is because as I said, `round` always gives integral-type results. However, you can always convert such an integral type to a `Double` again:

```
Prelude> [ c | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..4], let c = hyp a b, c == fromIntegral (round c)] :: [Double]
[5.0]
```

Note that this is not really a good solution though: you don't really want the result to be floating point if you go already check that the elements are really integral! I'd recommend in this case not just evaluating `hyp` as such at all. Better use this comprehension:

```
Prelude> [ c | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..4], let c² = a^2 + b^2; c = round . sqrt $ fromIntegral c², c^2==c²] :: [Integer]
[5]
```

One big argument for this version is that it does the comparison in `Integer`, not in `Double`. Floating-point equality comparison is something you should best stay away from entirely if you can help it; in this case it's *mostly* harmless because the interesting thing is the integer subset, which can in fact be represented exactly (unlike decimal fractions like `0.1`). Still you ca get wrong results this way: in particular, for sufficiently large floating-point numbers, `c == fromInteger (round c)` will *always* be true, because above a certain threshold all values are integral after all.

```
Prelude> [ c | a <- take 4 [1000000000000..], b <- take 5 [1000000000000..], let c = hyp a b, c == fromIntegral (round c)] :: [Float]
[1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12,1.4142135e12]
```

But none of these are actually correct integral hypothenuses, as you can see with the version that does the comparison in `Integer`:

```
Prelude> [ c | a <- take 4 [1000000000000..], b <- take 5 [1000000000000..], let c² = a^2 + b^2; c = round . sqrt $ fromIntegral c², c^2==c²] :: [Integer]
[]
```

Strictly speaking, this improved version is also not safe though – it doesn't give false positives, but may not find actual Pythagorean triples because the lossy floating-point steps can already destroy equality. To do it real properly, you need an all-integral

```
intSqrt :: Integral a => a -> Maybe a
```

This could probably done quite efficiently by taking the float `sqrt` as a starting value for a few rounds of pseudo [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson_method) in integer arithmetic.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>In principle, the `round` function could also have a more relaxed signature.</sub>

```
round' :: (Num b, RealFrac a) => a -> b
round' = fromInteger . round
```

<sub>With that version, your original code would work.</sub>